# How can I get direction from camera to an anchor

Tags: ios, arkit

I'm new to ARKit. I want to get the direction from anchor 1 to anchor 2. Currently, I can get the position from `transform.columns.3`. However, this works only for **fixed axis**.(z-axis always toward user)

How can I compare two anchor with respect to 6 axes (pitch, yaw, roll)? What should I read to get more detail information about this?

```
func showDirection(of object: ARAnchor) { // only work for fixed axis
    if let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame {
        print("diff(x) = \(currentFrame.camera.transform.columns.3.x - object.transform.columns.3.x)")
        print("diff(y) = \(currentFrame.camera.transform.columns.3.y - object.transform.columns.3.y)")
        print("diff(z) = \(currentFrame.camera.transform.columns.3.z - object.transform.columns.3.z)")
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'direction', rotation matrix? Here's a reference on quaternions - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd/working_with_quaternions , vectors - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd/working_with_vectors and matrices - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd/working_with_matrices

Comment: @MaximVolgin , thanks for your information, i was trying to lead user(left more, move 1 mile closer) to find an object

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer to [this other user's question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53054763/9505029) may be helpful. Basically, using SceneKit or ARKit, you can find the orientations of the camera and of your target anchor, and do some quaternion math to find the axis and angle of the relative rotation between them on x, y and z axes. My example assumed a SceneKit/ARKit app, which allows you to use quaternions instead of matrices, but the math should essentially be the same for ARKit transforms. If you use ARKit's `simd_float4x4` transform matrices, you could find one matrix in the space of the other (`A.inverse * B`) and use the resulting matrix to glean relative position and orientation.

Your question was a little hard to follow, as I'm not sure if the orientation of the anchor you're targeting matters in your case, but this should help as far as comparing two anchors with respect to pitch, yaw and roll.