# ARKit: How to tell if user's face is parallel to camera

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

In my `Swift` / `ARKit` / `SceneKit` project, I need to tell if the user's face in front-facing camera is parallel to the camera.

I was able to tell horizontal parallel by comparing the left and right eyes distance (using `faceAnchor.leftEyeTransform` and the `worldPosition` property) from the camera.

But I am stuck on vertical parallel. Any ideas, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you are using `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration` in your app, you can actually retrieve the transforms of both the `ARFaceAnchor` and the camera to determine their orientations. You can get a `simd_float4x4` matrix of the head's orientation in world space by using `ARFaceAnchor.transform` property. Similarly, you can get the transform of the `SCNCamera` or `ARCamera` of your scene.

To compare the camera's and face's orientations relative to each other in a SceneKit app (though there are similar functions on the ARKit side of things), I get the world transform for the node that is attached to each of them, let's call them `faceNode` attached to the `ARFaceAnchor` and `cameraNode` representing the `ARSCNView.pointOfView`. To find the angle between the camera and your face, for example, you could do something like this:

```
let faceOrientation: simd_quatf = faceNode.simdWorldTransform
let cameraOrientation: simd_quatf = cameraNode.simdWorldTransform
let deltaOrientation: simd_quatf = faceOrientation.inverse * cameraOrientation
```

By looking at `deltaOrientation.angle` and `deltaOrientation.axis` you can determine the relative angles on each axis between the face and the camera. If you do something like `deltaOrientation.axis * deltaOrientation.angles`, you have a `simd_float3` vector giving you a sense of the pitch, yaw and roll (in radians) of the head relative to the camera.

There are a number of ways you can do this using the face anchor and camera transforms, but this simd quaternion method works quite well for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer! can you share the source for your implementation if there is one?